# Variables and Buy Now options not appearing for configurable products

Tags: magento-1.9

Okay, so I'm in a very weird situation.

I migrated my website to a faster server and suddenly the options of `Add to Cart` & `Add to Wishlist` along with the `configurable options`, `upsell` products are not appearing on the product page of `configurable product`, however everything is working fine for simple products.

The problem is only with the `configurable products`. **Product images, descriptions, title & price** are appearing, but not the above cited things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things you can do:

1. Check status & quantity of all associated products in the configurable products.
2. Clear magento caches+ redis caches.
3. Do all the indexing `Admin->System->Index Management`

If still issue is there then for sure some **code level** issue is there.

Comment: Actually few extension files were conflicting with the theme files resulting into this mess. I got the details from exception.log file, but thanks anyway for the answer & your time. :)